# Displaying dynamic checkbox in listview with select all option

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I am trying to display dynamic checkboxes on long item press in a listview. I am able to successfully get the checkboxes and the select all also works. But I feel the code is quite complex and causes getView to be called multiple times. Can anyone please suggest a better way to my implementation? 
Also, I am fetching albumArt in async task inside getView and due to multiple times getView is called due to dynamic checkbox, I get GC freed msgs so many times in Logcat . Here is my code:

Activity:

```
songView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            longClickpressed = true;
            chkSelectAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            songAdt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });
 chkSelectAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < songAdt.getCount(); i++) {

                songList.get(i).setSelected(chkSelectAll.isChecked());
            }
            songAdt.selectAll(chkSelectAll.isChecked());
            songAdt.unCheckAll(chkSelectAll.isChecked());
            songAdt.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Adapter class:

```
 public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 int countChecked = 0;
 private boolean checkable = false;
 boolean selectAll2 = false;
 boolean checkable2 = true;
 int countreload=-1;
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    checkBoxCounter = 0;
    checkBoxInitialized = 0;
    View view = convertView;

    final int pos = position;

    if (view == null) {
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, parent, false);
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_song_title);
        holder.tvArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_song_artist);
        holder.chkItem = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkLvItem);
        holder.imgAlbumArt = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img_lv_album_art);

        holder.chkItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    countChecked++;
                    countreload++;

                } else {
                    countChecked--;
                    countreload--;
                }

                Song element1 = (Song) holder.chkItem.getTag();
                element1.setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
                setTitleActivity(countChecked);
                if (checkBoxCounter <= checkBoxInitialized) {
                    // increment counter, when we scroll the List it
                    // execute onCheckedChanged everytime so by
                    // using this stuff we can maintain the state
                    checkBoxCounter++;
                } else {
                    Song element2 = (Song) holder.chkItem.getTag();
                    element2.setSelected(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());

                }
            }
        });
        view.setTag(holder);
        holder.chkItem.setTag(songs.get(position));

    } else {
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).chkItem.setTag(songs.get(position));
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.tvArtist.setText(songs.get(position).getArtist());
    holder.tvTitle.setText(songs.get(position).getTitle());
    if (checkable) {
        holder.chkItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (selectAll2) {

            countChecked = songs.size();
            songs.get(position).setSelected(selectAll2);
            holder.chkItem.setChecked(selectAll2);
            setTitleActivity(countChecked);

        } else if (!selectAll2 && !checkable2 && countreload==-1) {

            countChecked = 0;
            songs.get(position).setSelected(selectAll2);
            holder.chkItem.setChecked(selectAll2);
            setTitleActivity(countChecked);
        }


    }
    holder.chkItem.setChecked(songs.get(position).isSelected());

    long albumId = songs.get(position).getAlbumId();
    long songId = songs.get(position).getAudioId();

    if (BitmapWorkerAsyncTask.cancelPotentialWork(albumId,
            holder.imgAlbumArt)) {
        final BitmapWorkerAsyncTask task = new BitmapWorkerAsyncTask(
                holder.imgAlbumArt, mContext);
        final BitmapWorkerAsyncTask.AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = new BitmapWorkerAsyncTask.AsyncDrawable(
                mContext.getResources(), mLoadingBitmap, task);
        holder.imgAlbumArt.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(view, songId, albumId, mContext, 1);

    }
 return view;}
public void unCheckAll(boolean checkable1) {
    checkable2 = checkable1;
}
public void selectAll(boolean selectAll) {
    selectAll2 = selectAll;
}
```